# How to get the license text for Google Maps on Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, xamarin, nuget

I'm using the Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps NuGet. Google documentation tells me display the text of the license in my app, saying

> You can get the attribution text by making a call to [GMSServices openSourceLicenseInfo]

Fine, however the NuGet does not support GMSServices, and after searching high and low I can't find the license text anywhere on the web.

How do I get the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[GMSServices openSourceLicenseInfo]` equals `Google.Maps.MapServices.OpenSourceLicenseInfo` in Xamarin.

re: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/b4d46b01784fc0c30ad2553b0307e0923586cff4/source/Google/Maps/ApiDefinition.cs#L1244

> Attribution Requirements
>
> If you use the Google Maps SDK for iOS in your application, you must include the attribution text as part of a legal notices section in your application. Including legal notices as an independent menu item, or as part of an "About" menu item, is recommended.
>
> You can get the attribution text by making a call to `Google.Maps.MapServices.OpenSourceLicenseInfo`

Comment: Much appreciated, SushiHangover